# What does "Call all Node.js modules directly from DOM"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

above question is in context of nwjs.
How does DOM call nodejs module? 
What is DOM here (just tree constructed representing elements or methods)?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is basically your html page structure. What it means is that you can call any Node.JS module you want from inside a DOM element (i.e. from the code in a `script` tag).